# How to use / configure the Course Requirements module?

Tags: 7

When using the [Course](https://www.drupal.org/project/course) module, you may also want to use the [Course Requirements](https://www.drupal.org/project/course_requirements) module, so that a user cannot be enrolled in a 2nd course until a 1st course is completed.

However, it's not obvious how to actually use / configure the [Course Requirements](https://www.drupal.org/project/course_requirements) module. So how is this module supposed to be used/configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Course Requirements](https://www.drupal.org/project/course_requirements) module does not have a lot (any?) docu. But [comment nr 3 of issue # 2148985](https://www.drupal.org/node/2148985#comment-8236797) helps to make it work, i.e.:

1. Add a node reference field to your Course content type (to references other courses).
2. Go to `admin/config/course/requirements` and select that node reference field you just added.
3. Add courses through the node reference field.

After completing these steps, this is how it should work:

- The courses you add in the field should block that course from being enrolled into without completing the referenced courses.
- After completing a course it should also tell you what courses required that course for completion.